# Parameter expansion

Tags: shell

I've been playing around with parameter expansion. The following is my code.

```
a="one"
sh -c 'echo $a'

b="two"
sh -c "echo $b"

c="three" sh -c 'echo $c'
echo $c
```

And this is the output when i execute this script:

```
$sh test.sh

two
three

$
```

For $a, If single quoting suppresses substitution. Shouldn't it just print echo $a ? It's printing a new line, does that mean that the value of $a is null? For $c, the 'echo $c' doesn't work, doesn't print a new line, but the echo $c in the next line works as intended. I'm a little confused how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see variables in subprocesses, you have to `export` them. Like this:

```
   $ export a=7
   $ sh -c 'echo $a'
   7
```

In your case, subprocesses (for `a` and `b`) don't see variables from parent shell.

When you make string with single quotes, all substitutions don't work. You cannot substitute variable or something like `\n`. It will be exactly `$a` or `\n`. So, string in first case is exactly 'echo $a'. `sh -c 'echo $a'` will create **new** process, and this process won't have parent's `$a`, it will have it's own uninitialized `$a`, i. e. empty string. It will just execution of `'echo $a'`

In second case, you are using double quotes. Substitution works, and string becomes `"echo two"` **before** execution subprocess. So, it's just execution `sh -c 'echo two'`.

In third case, `$c` becomes exported variable. It is special syntax that means «export variable only for this command». Thus, you execute exactly `sh -c 'echo $c'`, but new shell will contain `$c` as an environment variable. Like `$PATH` or `$HOME` when you start your shell.

Answer (score 4):

`sh -c 'echo $a'` is like opening a new shell and typing `echo $a` in it.
Since there's no variable `a` in the child shell (you didn't `export` the one you set in the parent shell), it'll print an empty line.

With

```
b="two"
sh -c "echo $b"
```

, the `"echo $b"` string is expanded by the current shell and the expanded value is passed as an argument string to the 
child shell. It's as if you opened a new shell and typed in `echo two`.

`var=val command` temporarily sets and `export`s `var=val`, just for the invocation of `command`.

```
c="three" sh -c 'echo $c'
```

is almost (the subshell isn't really there) like

```
( export c="three"; sh -c 'echo $c' )
```

The c variable in the parent shell is not affected.